# Linux : need help in finding the syntax error (line 3)

Tags: bash, syntax

So, the idea is to insert all the active users who have user id `-le 500` into a mysql table.

The syntax error is at line 3; I've searched the whole script and still haven't found it.

Here's the script :

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in $(cat /etc/passwd) do

    username=`echo $name | cut -d : -f1`
    userid=`echo $name | cut -d : -f3`
    userpass=`cat /etc/shadow | grep $username | cut -d : -f2`

    if [[ "`expr $userpass`" =~ "!" ]]; then
        echo "$username is disabled, skipped
    else
        if [[ $userid -le 500 ]]; then
            echo "User id of $username is over 500, skipped"
        else
            fullname=`echo $name | cut -d : -f5`
                    "INSERT INTO`mailbox`(username,`password`,`name`,`maildir`,`quota`,`local_part`,`domain`,`created`,`modified`,active)VALUES($username,'$pass','$fullname$',0,'xxx','date --rfc3339=date','date --rfc3339=date',1)
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this kind of coding but a quick Google search it looks as though the "f1", "f2", "f3", "f5" should all have spacing. "f 1", "f 2", "f 3", "f 5"

Comment: No it works, i've used it countless of times

Comment: Please [edit] your question and write out again only the line containing the syntax error so that I don't accidentally choose the wrong line 3.

Comment: Please check your script with https://www.shellcheck.net/ There are way to many issues, deprecated code, missing quotes to detail each one here. Once you have dealt with each issue raised by ShellCheck and if you are still struggling with some, then post specific question. I know you can not edit your post with only 1 reputation point.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i solved the issue! turns out it was indeed the semicolon in the for statement hehe

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error here is a missing `;` before `do`.

```
for name in $(cat /etc/passwd) do
```

should be

```
for name in $(cat /etc/passwd); do
```

After you added the `;` also add a closing `"` in `echo "$username is disabled, skipped`. Besides these syntax errors there are many things you could improve in your script. I recommend https://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: Oh my, that did the trick. thanks :), i'll solve the remaining remaining errors and fix the other problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon in your line 3:

```
for name in $(cat /etc/passwd); do
```

Comment: BTW, there are plenty of other problems in this script: missing double quote symbols, strings like commands...